# How to translate LOGIN and REGISTER?

Tags: перевод, информатика

How can i translate LOGIN and REGISTER in webdesign context?

How can also translate CLIENT LOGIN - EMAIL - USERNAME - PASSWORD - LOGOUT ?

What i have found are these:

LOGIN - **логин** 
REGISTER - **регистрировать** 
CLIENT LOGIN - **Логин клиента** 
EMAIL - **е-мейл** 
USERNAME - **имя пользователя** 
PASSWORD - **пароль** 
LOGOUT - **выйти**

I would like to use these words exactly how they are commonly used in russian websites?

Comment: I'm not sure the question is on topic. Translation questions that show no previous attempts are rather unwelcome.

Comment: Ok i have edited the question, putting the translations find by myself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
username         - имя пользователя 
the login        - имя пользователя/логин
to login         - войти
an account       - учётная запись
to register      - зарегистрироваться
registration     - регистрация
e-mail           - е-мейл/почта
password         - пароль
to logout        - выйти
the client login - вход для клиентов
```

Comment: Thank you!
CLIENT LOGIN is a section reserved for client/customer of the site

Comment: @johnnyfittizio That's strange. I hevent seen the a member-only section of the site called "login". Can you provide an example? Are you talking about the profile page and the account settings page? Are you talking about websites with shared member-only sections?

Comment: For example a site for car rental. The registration is reserved for clients only. So there will be written CLIENT LOGIN

Comment: @johnnyfittizio вход для клиентов then

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using "Е-мейл". It's merely a colloquial form yet. Use "Адрес электронной почты", "Эл. почта" or just "Почта" instead.

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: Colloquial for e-mail is "мыло" and to email is "намылить".