# How to translate “You are not logged in” into Russian

Tags: перевод, информатика

The computer terms *login*/*logout* are commonly translated as *вход*/*выход* or *войти*/*выйти*. I am struggling, however, with the expressions:

> You are not logged in

and

> Please log in first

I could translate the former as *вы не вошли*, but *вошли куда* (where)? The same with the latter: *Пожалуйста, сначала войдите* — again, enter what?

In English, the verb *to log in* implies a computer environment. In Russian, the corresponding word *входить* has no such connotation. I could say *войти на сайт*, but that would be wrong again, since the user *is* already in my site, he should just log in.

Related question: [How to translate LOGIN and REGISTER?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4106)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Пожалуйста, войдите/зайдите на форум.
2. Пожалуйста, введите Ваше имя (Ваш ник) и пароль.

Comment: With войдите/зайдите — the user is already in the site, so what should he enter? With username and password, it's a good request for a page where he can actually enter the credentials. What about an error page, that the user sees when trying to access a page requiring authorization?

Comment: Probably, the previous advice (авторизироваться) is the best.

Comment: @texnic however, "зайти на форум" обычно означает не просто открыть в браузере страничку с форумом, а и ввести логин/пароль.

Comment: Agree, however in my case you need to login just to access the whole site. I.e. you cannot see anything unless you've been authorised. But your answer gave me a good hint. I've decided to avoid the first message and just redirect the user to the login page, where I'll use a version of your second sentence. So I accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @user31264 You could add one more, a bit creative variant "Войдите под своим именем". It is also occasionally used

Answer (score 13):

> Вы не авторизованы
>   Пожалуйста, авторизируйтесь

Comment: Минусующим: объясните за что минус. Автору: было бы неплохо прокомментировать почему ваш вариант подходит спрашивающему. Это поможет не только ему но и тем кто в будущем будет искать ответ на похожий вопрос.

Comment: I like the option, though shouldn't it be [авторизоваться](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)?

Comment: Yes, it can be. There is no mistake

Comment: Contrary to the popular belief, the sign-in process is mainly *authentication*, not *authorization*.

Comment: Authorization is providing credentials for check. Authentication is granting permissions to the authorized user according to his membership plan and etc. Hence authorization is the most applicable word here.

Comment: It is true that authentication and authorization are different thing and in this context the first one is usually meant, but it is a common pattern to use and the word "авторизованый" is used in Russian to mean "approved", "valid" so the meaning would be clear to most people.

Comment: @AlexanderElgin what you described (providing credentials, i.e. establishing who you are) is authentication. Authorization comes after and figures out if you (as established by credentials) is allowed to do what you are asking to do.

Comment: AlexanderElgin has it mixed up, and StashM is absolutely correct. From the Microsoft Technet: "Authentication is the verification of the credentials..." and "Authorization occurs after successful authentication."
Based on this a better answer would be: "идентифицируйте себя"

Comment: Providing credentials is authorization. Establishing what rights you have is authentication. "идентифицируйте себя" is a bull shit in this case. Nobody uses it.

Comment: @AlexanderElgin Providing credentials is authentication. Establishing what rights you have is authorization.

Answer (score 6):

Простой народ не парится, пишет "вы не залогинились", "сначала залогиньтесь".

Народ посложнее пишет "вы не вошли в систему", "сначала войдите в систему".
Согласитесь, загадочная "система" таинственнее, чем просто сайт. Это нечто другое.

Авторизация - тоже неплохо, но как-то заумно.

Ещё модно приплетать полномочия.
"Подтвердите Ваши полномочия". Каждое слово по-русски!

Answer (score 3):

«Пожалуйста, выполните вход» is widely used in this sense. «Залогиниться» is too informal, «авторизоваться» is a correct form but non-native.

Comment: Native or not, "выполните вход" is an utter solecism.

Answer (score 1):

```
Пожалуйста, авторизируйтесь = Please, login first
Вы не прошли идентификацию = You are not logged in
```

Answer (score -4):

[log](https://www.etymonline.com/word/log?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_12388) (n.1) "piece of wood." (n.2) General sense "any record of facts entered in order" is by 1913

log - бревно, чурка, болванка.

to log - упорядочивание, занесение в протокол, считывание наблюдений.

Please, login first - приятно сперва упорядочиться/ приятно быть оболваненным сперва.

You are not logged in - вы не занесены в протокол/ вы не оболванены.